# Is it possible to access class properties without initialising the class?

Tags: javascript, class

I want to access all of the properties of a class that will be defined when the constructor is called, so that I can implement a sort of interface for the class.

Say I had a class that defines the property `hello`, I would like to access it to check it has been implemented and the type assigned to it is correct. Problem is, since all non-`static` class properties are tied to an instance, I can't get at them without instantiating the class, which I can't do.

In this situation, is it possible to access `hello`?

```
class MyClass {
    constructor () {
        this.hello = 'greetings';
    }
}
```

Comment: Access instance properties without an instance - by definition, no, you can't. This sounds like an XY problem - what are you *actually trying to achieve*

Comment: JavaScript is a dynamic language. You seem to want one that's static. TypeScript might give you what you need.

Comment: _"which I can't do."_ Why?

Comment: Create a temporary instance to get those property names, that's the simplest way.

Comment: You either want Typescript with proper static type checking; or you want to do this at runtime at which point I fail to see a scenario where you'd have to do this on a class and not an instance of one… some clarification would go a long way here.

Comment: You can parse the `class` using `RegExp`, though curious why the procedure _"access it to check it has been implemented and the type assigned to it is correct"_  is necessary?

Comment: _"I want to access all of the properties of a class"_ Note, the `class` has only one property, the `constructor`. Are you trying to check if `this.hello` is a string?

Answer (score 3):

> In this situation, is it possible to access `hello`?

Not without using a JavaScript parser (like IDEs do to try to infer instance mbmers). `hello`, as you say, doesn't exist as a property until/unless an instance is created. With a parser, you can (usually) determine what the property names will be, perhaps sometimes their initial values, but that's all.

Comment: Even with a parser, `this[some + expression] = 'value'` is still possible and basically impossible to catch.

Comment: @deceze: Hence "usually" :-)

Comment: Or `let self = this; self.foo = 'bar';`… Sorry, just piling on various scenarios here… :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156572/discussion-on-answer-by-t-j-crowder-is-it-possible-to-access-class-properties-w).