# Determine the type of value of a declared property within a class using RegExp, String or other methods

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, types

Given

```
class MyClass {
    constructor () {
        this.hello = 'greetings';
    }
}
```

how can we determine if `this.hello` is expected to be one of the JavaScript types, for example, `String`, `Array`, `Boolean`, without initiating the `class`?

For the purposes of the inquiry we are not concerned with the practicality of the procedure, but rather, to what extent the procedure is possible and verifiable.

For example

```
let c = MyClass.toString().match(/constructor\s\(?.+\)\s\{?\n.+\n.+\‌​}/); 
c[0].match(/this\.\w+?\s=?\s.*(?:;)/);
```

we can get `this.hello = 'greeting';`, which are the next steps to determine that `'greeting'` is expected to be or will be a string?

What are the issues with utilizing `RegExp` or `String` methods to achieve requirement?

---

For clarification of requirement:

Given any arbitrary JavaScript class, determine the type of the arguments used in its constructor.

Comment: Use a parser, parse the source code. Do not use regex to do any of that.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a viable approach. E.g. `this.hello = 'greetings hi howdy'.split()` would mean that `hello` is an `Array`, but to get it right, your regex would have to be able to interpret what `String.prototype.split` returns. IMO, you'll have better luck with a full on parser / AST than a regex.

Comment: @Tomalak Can you post your observations and suggestions at an Answer?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Can you formulate an Answer describing the issues with such and approach for posterity?

Comment: Is this for exercise and curiosity, or what is the reason for not being able to instantiate the class?

Comment: @KevBot This grew out of [a discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156572/discussion-on-answer-by-t-j-crowder-is-it-possible-to-access-class-properties-w) whether it's practically possible to parse Javascript via regexen, which in turn grew out of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711922/is-it-possible-to-access-class-properties-without-initialising-the-class) which isn't really relevant. And no, nobody knows why the class can't be instantiated originally. ;)

Comment: BTW, let me commend you in the intellectual rigor you bring to this. Secondly, if “regular expressions cannot match non-regular languages” doesn’t satisfy you, a formal proof would involve something along the lines of showing that the string “constructor” can appear in any number of nested contexts (in strings, comments, method names, functions within functions), none of which are *a constructor*, and showing that regular expressions are ill equipped to distinguish between these contexts. (That’s basically what distinguishes regular languages from other things.)

Comment: @deceze If we had a predefined pattern used at `class` the requirement could probably be achieve with less trial and error. Though the premise of the linked Question appeared to be first locating a pattern, if any, then trying to match unknown values. The conclusion might indeed be impractically achievable, and difficult to verify results at all.

Comment: @deceze We could check all occurrences of `/=(?=\s+["'\`]|["'\`])/` to match string value, though values could also be assigned using `Object.assign()`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex for this; the complexity of JavaScript's syntax is just too much for simple regular expressions. Instead, use a parser and walk the AST.

Here's a pretty crude stab at it using [acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn). This will only capture properties declared in the form,

```
this.<propName> = <literal>;
```

but it demonstrates the basic concept.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    this.hello = 'greetings';
  }
}

var ast = acorn.parse(MyClass.toString());
document.write(`Class: '${ast.body[0].id.name}'<br>`);
var ctor = ast.body[0].body.body.find(fn => fn.kind == "constructor");
ctor.value.body.body.forEach(x =>
  x.type == "ExpressionStatement" && 
  x.expression.type == "AssignmentExpression" && 
  x.expression.left.type == "MemberExpression" &&
  x.expression.left.object.type == "ThisExpression" &&
  x.expression.left.property.type == "Identifier" &&
  x.expression.right.type == "Literal" &&
  document.write(`&emsp;Property '${x.expression.left.property.name}' of type '${typeof(x.expression.right.value)}'<br>`));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/5.1.2/acorn.js"></script>
```